# Some Snow Leopard machines taking a very long time to log in (AD, Win2k3)

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, login, osx-snow-leopard

We have some iMacs that are taking a very long time to log with AD credentials, whereas other machines on the network take the normal amount of time.  What sort of thing could be happening?

They're running 10.6.8 and the server is Windows 2003.

Thanks

Comment: You should really update this question with meaningful content that would help us solve your problem. As it is, anything will only be a guess. A good start would be dumps of the console logs from the long login.

Answer (score 1):

try to verify the DNS settings of iMac.
most of times such issues are due to un-responsive dns name resolution.
also look at the auth log in iMac, it might give some clue.